# How to restore missing missing chainloader in dual boot setup

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I installed windows successfully on a blank Dell laptop then installed Ubutnu 18.04 from a pen drive successfully.  I was hoping this would create a dual boot system.

When I restart I first see a text output that says

```
Invalid Partition Table!
```

And then the familiar purple screen and ubuntu loads. No option to load windows.
grub.cfg does not have the chainloader option.
os-prober does not seem to find windows.
I have rerun update-grub

Do I have any options that don't involve re-installing windows, it took a 3 or 4 hours to complete the windows install.

UEFI boot seems to be involved.  I disabled it in the bios to be able to install both windows and linux